# What does it mean when submission system says "under review" after submitting minor revisions?

Tags: phd

Is it possible that after sending minor revisions my paper has gone for a fresh review again. I had received the following recommendation: accept subject to optional revision. The status has been showing " under review " for a month now.

Is it still with the associate editor or with the old reviewers. I got two referred comments and one guest editor comments 
Sent my paper to ieee transaction

Comment: Well, it is certainly gone for a review; what do you mean by "fresh"?

Comment: @peter. By fresh I mean ha it gone to the earlier reviewers or new ones considering that the earlier reviewers gave me a recommendation: accept subject toniptional revisions

Answer (score 1):

In most of the article submission systems the "Under Review" status means your manuscript is with reviewers. Most probably it must be sent to the old reviewers but there is also a possibility that editor might invite a new reviewer. It happened to me, one of my article which went through 2 revisions, 1 major and 1 minor took 1 year, and it was rejected because editor invited a 4th reviewer who raised few concerns. 
Best of luck for your article.